# ajax auto complete function cannot find textbox (Cannot read properties of null)

Tags: asp.net, autocomplete

I have textbox need to suggest auto complete names for the user so I follow up this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yUc6OVaeWi8)

I do every sub parts well the issue with autocomplete function always cannot find the element by Id.

I try to :

- put script at the bottom of body
- check id value correct by debugger
- make sure asp call id correct
- in debugger mode the compiler does not go into autocomplete function

what I miss?

code:

```
<html><head>
...
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
<script src="vendor/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
..
</head>
<body>
...
<asp:TextBox ID="AssetName" placeholder="AssetName" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
...
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" >
        $(document).ready(function () {
            debugger;
            var id = "#" + '<%=AssetName.ClientID%>';
            $(id).autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    var param = {
                        Name: $(id).val()
                    };
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "AddInventoryItem.aspx/getNames",
                        data: JSON.stringify(param),
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    value: item
                                }
                            }))
                        },
                        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            var err = eval("(" + XMLHttpRequest.responseText + ")");
                            alert(err.Message)
                            console.log("Ajax Error!");
                        }
                    });
                },
                minLength: 1 //This is the Char length of inputTextBox    
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
<html>
```

browser error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, you not provided your server-side code. And no one here is going to watch some video on YT. So, a suggesting in the future is to provide your code behind.

So, let's drop in a text box, and search for a List of Hotels.

So, our markup:

```
<div style="padding: 35px">
    <h3>Enter Hotel</h3>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtHotel" runat="server">
    </asp:TextBox>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=txtHotel.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "DateLessOne.aspx/HotelSearch",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ HotelName: request.term }),
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                value: item
                            }
                        }))
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have "ignored" issues like how many matches, and after how many characters you want to start showing matches. (Baby steps here, baby steps). I suggest for ease and keeping this simple, if you want to show results say only after 3 characters typed, then do that test server side.

Our code behind is this:

```
<WebMethod()>
Public Shared Function HotelSearch(HotelName As String) As List(Of String)

    Dim HotelList As New List(Of String)
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Dim strSQL As String =
            "SELECT HotelName FROM tblHotels
             WHERE HotelName like @h + '%' ORDER BY HotelName"
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@h", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = HotelName
            conn.Open()
            Dim rstData As New DataTable
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
            For Each dRow As DataRow In rstData.Rows
                HotelList.Add(dRow("HotelName").ToString())
            Next
        End Using
    End Using

    Return HotelList

End Function
```

And the result is thus this:

[image]